# Xubuntu software update not working?

Tags: xubuntu, software-updater

When running a software update, I got a message telling me that either my network connections aren't working anymore, or that the repositories are no longer available. I already tried restarting my computer and running the software updater from the settings panel. I am running Xubuntu 13.04. Software Uupdate has worked in the past.

`sudo apt-get update` gives me the following output: (I had to take out the big chunk of links because I am not allowed to post more than 2 links)

```
Ign cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1) raring Release.gpg
Ign cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1) raring Release
Err cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1) raring/main amd64 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1) raring/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1) raring/restricted amd64 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1) raring/universe amd64 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1) raring/main i386 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1) raring/multiverse i386 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1) raring/restricted i386 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1) raring/universe i386 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Ign cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1) raring/main Translation-en_US
Ign cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1) raring/main Translation-en
Ign cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1) raring/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1) raring/multiverse Translation-en
Ign cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1) raring/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1) raring/restricted Translation-en
Ign cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1) raring/universe Translation-en_US
Ign cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1) raring/universe Translation-en
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fetched 950 kB in 10s (88.0 kB/s)                                              
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 977C43A8BA684223
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1)/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1)/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1)/dists/raring/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1)/dists/raring/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1)/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1)/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1)/dists/raring/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Xubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130423.1)/dists/raring/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: [Edit] your answer with the output of `sudo apt-get update`. Otherwise, it's very difficult to answer this question.

Comment: What on earth did you do?  You have 27 duplicate cdrom entries, and the one non cdrom source seems to be pointing to opensuse?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the Xubuntu 13.04 CD-ROM software source from your Software Sources. Select Xubuntu mouse icon in top left corner -> *Ubuntu Software Center* -> *Edit* -> *Software Sources* -> *Other Software* tab. Uncheck the checkbox to the left of where it says: Cdrom with Xubuntu 13.04 'Raring Ringtail'.

Comment: I actually had to uncheck the cdrom from the next tab over, "Other Software". That fixed the issue.